# Excel VBA crashes when copying worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Excel is crashing at the 'ws.Copy' line of code below

Details:

- This function is called at approximately 80% of the way through my ~2500 lines of code
- No crash when running the related subroutine on its own, only when running the full code
- I am running this function on Excel 2013
- I am able to copy the worksheet manually without Excel crashing
- It will crash both while running the script and while stepping through (F8)
- The program only crashes when run on a Windows computer
- It didn't always crash, this just randomly started happening

What I've tried:

- I have tried 'DoEvents' before and after the function call
- I have tried 'Application.wait'

---

```
    Option Explicit
    ...
```

---

```
    Function Copy_Template(dict As Collection)
        Dim strKey As Variant
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set ws = Sheets("Template")

        For Each strKey In dict
            If strKey <> "" Then
                ' Windows machine is crashing at this line for no reason!!!
                ws.Copy After:=Sheets("Summary")
                ActiveSheet.Name = strKey
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Comment: I think it may have to do with the number of complex formulas in the worksheet being copied but I can't be sure.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, the really odd thing is I copy a sheet from another workbook right before that without incident, but when I get to this new one, it crashes reliably. I have done integrity checks on both files and "repaired" them both, but it seems to want to crash. Did you ever figure this out?